# JMH - run without Maven

Tags: java, jmh

I am trying to setup the very basic JMH test suite but I cannot get through to generate the jar with the tests... I have annotation processor on the classpath, with jmh core too, one simple class but when I run `Main.main()` there are no jars being generated (running it from IntelliJ). Is there some parameter/option I am missing when running?

Comment: I think you need to use maven because jmh uses the shade plugin which auto-generates some code based on your benchmarks (i.e. JMH does not run your benchmarks as you write them but a modified version that deals with various JIT optimisations). I may be wrong.

Comment: JAR generation is not required to run JHM benchmarks. Just make sure that annotation processing is enabled in `Settings/Compiler/Annotation Processors` and JHM processor is endeed on the compilation classpath. The correct code will be generated during normal compilation process.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin - Awersome, that is precisely what I was lacking. All other bits were there.

Comment: You might find this useful http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/02/jmh-how-to-setup-and-run-jmh-benchmark.html

Comment: If you only have `jmh-core`on your classpath you further need `jmh-generator-annprocess`dependency

Comment: Thanks, worked for me similarly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot not generate `benchmarks.jar` without `maven-shade-plugin`.

If you still want to run from the command line but without `benchmarks.jar` you can copy the command IDEA executes from the console and run it from terminal.